# Why can't I push data to Firebase from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am starting out on a project with node.js and Firebase realtime database which develops a REST API. I have been struggling to connect and push data to firebase. Since I intend to use the MVC structure, I plan to separate out my model as shown in the `user.js` file below. Please have a look at my code:

```
/* user.js */

function User (id, firstName, lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName= lastName;
}

const config = {
    apiKey: "....",
    authDomain: "....",
    databaseURL: "....",
    projectId: "....",
    storageBucket: "....",
    messagingSenderId: "...."
}

const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const database = firebase.database();
const userRef = database.ref('/users');

User.prototype.post = () => {
    console.log(this.id);

    //just to test whether the database is connected
    //ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities
    userRef.on("value", function(snap) {
        if (snap.val() === true) {
          console.log("connected");
        } else {
          console.log("not connected");
        }
      });

    userRef.child(this.id).set({
        firstName: this.firstName,
        lastName: this.lastName
    });
}
module.exports = User;

/* index.js */

const User = require('./user')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    const {id, firstName, lastName} = req.body;
    const user = new User (id, firstName, lastName);
    //console.log(user);
    user.post();
    res.send("Success!");
}

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

When I try sending a POST request, the data is not being pushed to the firebase database. I also get `"not connected"` for the code that tests whether the database is connected (see `user.js`). Could someone please guide me on where I am going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: I should mention that when I try doing everything in a single `index.js` file, this works fine. However, I want to separate out the `user.js` model.

Comment: If you are calling the Real Time Database directly from your server, i.e. "from a privileged environment", you should better use the Admin SDK, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Comment: If `userRef.on("value", function(snap) {` calls back, it means your client is actually connected to the database despite the fact that you log that it's not. If you write a value with `userRef..set(true);` right after the `on("value"`, does it work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That worked - I managed to set the value to True in the database. Thanks for that! 
When I tried to `console.log(this.id)` or `(this.firstName)`, I am getting `undefined`. I suspect this is the problem. Any ideas of how I can solve this?